# C++ MSXML, LINK error "already defined in obj"

Tags: c++, mfc, include, msxml, lnk2005

I don't understand what I did wrong

***Common.h***

```
#pragma once
#include "Flisr.h"
#import <msxml3.dll> named_guids
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr   m_plDomDocument;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMElementPtr    m_pDocRoot;
```

***Common.cpp***

```
#include "Common.h"

//some functions
```

***Flisr.cpp***

```
#include "Flisr.h"
#include "Common.h"

//some functions from Common
```

Errors are:

```
error LNK2005: "class _com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument,&struct __s_GUID const _GUID_2933bf81_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60> > m_plDomDocument" (?m_plDomDocument@@3V?$_com_ptr_t@V?$_com_IIID@UIXMLDOMDocument@MSXML2@@$1?_GUID_2933bf81_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60@@3U__s_GUID@@B@@@@A) already defined in Common.obj

error LNK2005: "class _com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct MSXML2::IXMLDOMElement,&struct __s_GUID const _GUID_2933bf86_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60> > m_pDocRoot" (?m_pDocRoot@@3V?$_com_ptr_t@V?$_com_IIID@UIXMLDOMElement@MSXML2@@$1?_GUID_2933bf86_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60@@3U__s_GUID@@B@@@@A) already defined in Common.obj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you `"#include "Common.h"`, you are defining a new set of objects (global variables) called `m_plDomDocument` and `m_pDocRoot`.  Only one of each is permitted for the scope of the program, hence the error that they are already defined.

Comment: Almost correct. Should read *"Each time you `#include "Common.h"` into a new compilation unit, [...]"*. Multiple `#include "Common.h"` directives when compiling a single compilation unit are guarded by `#pragma once` and don't cause any issues.